# Full scan of long table with huge amount of versions results only small part of rows

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, nosql

I have case where I need to scan table with about 50 columns and every column containing about 100 versions. Nothing special (`this.htable` is just appropriate `HTable` and `processor` is intended to handle resulting rows):

```
    final Scan scan = new Scan();
    scan.setCaching(1000);
    scan.setMaxVersions(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    final ResultScanner rs = this.table.getScanner(scan);
    try {
        for (Result r = rs.next(); r != null; r = rs.next()) {
            processor.processRow(r);
        }
    } finally {
        rs.close();
    }
```

When I try to scan in such approach table with about 20 x 10^6 rows I get only about 50 x 10^3 rows. No special configuration is applied for scanner, HBase is 0.98.1 (CDH5.1). What do I miss in this? Is it some HBase drawback or I do something seriously wrong? What can I check? I have checked result size limit (not a case) and you see maxVersions is configured. Who can limit such scans?

**UPDATE**
It was checked returned `Result` instances and their `Cell` instances inside are seriously different in number from expected results. Yet another time, table was about 20 x 10^6 rows which could be counted by the same code without maximum versions configuration. And returned number of rows WITH versions is about 50 * 10^3.

Comment: Roman, did you also tried to scan table in `hbase shell`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you have in processRow. But key-value pairs is inside result object. For one row key there can be many key-value pairs you know. May be this can be the missing point

```
for (Result result : resultScanner) {
  for (KeyValue kv : result.raw()) {
   Bytes.toString(kv.getQualifier());
   Bytes.toString(kv.getValue());
   Bytes.toString(result.getRow());
  }
 }
```

Comment: Result is not for several rows. It stores only one row and even if I could miss some columns I should get correct row counter: https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Result.html, But I have wrong one.